# Path filter regex in GETftp processor in apache nifi

Tags: apache, ftp, apache-nifi, pipeline

Hello guys I'm trying to get all xls files from all folders in a ftp serveur and I'm using a regular expression in PATH FILTER regex but with no result and when I'm putting the absolute path like '/TEST/TEST/' I'm getting the files
Here's the confiuration :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfmjg.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set these properties:

- `Search Recursively` to `true`;
- `File Filter Regex` to `*.xls`;
- and leave `Path Filter Regex` to its default value.